# Augury not showing component states

Tags: angular, debugging

[Augury](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/augury/elgalmkoelokbchhkhacckoklkejnhcd) which is chrome extension to debug angular application was working fine earlier but it doesn't show any states now.

I'm using angular version 5.1.0 and augury version 1.16.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

edit src/polyfills.ts and comment this line out:

```
// import 'core-js/es6/date';
```

Comment: that's the source: https://github.com/rangle/augury/issues/1351#issuecomment-454381790

Answer (score 1):

I'll suggest you to take a look at the [Augury's GitHub repo](https://github.com/rangle/augury) and its [related issues](https://github.com/rangle/augury/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=component%20state).

It seems that [you aren't the only one to face this issue](https://github.com/rangle/augury/issues/1283).

Augury team is investigating, maybe your issue will be fixed in a next release.

Comment: Yes I'm having a close look at Augury's GitHub repo, I was hoping if there is any hack or temporary work around  so that I can inspect states.

Answer (score 0):

A new version of `Angular DevTools` has been released. You can get it from [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angular-devtools/ienfalfjdbdpebioblfackkekamfmbnh?hl=en&authuser=0)(Chrome webstore).

- You can read more on [medium blog](https://blog.angular.io/introducing-angular-devtools-2d59ff4cf62f)
- You can check in [github issue](https://github.com/rangle/augury/issues/1507) page also.
- Offline downloadable [Augury](https://www.crx4chrome.com/crx/28179/)